# acces tuple inside a tuple for anonymous map job in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, word-count

> This post is essentially about how to build joint and marginal histograms from a (String, String) RDD. I posted the code that I eventually used below as the answer.

I have an `RDD` that contains a set of tuples of type `(String,String)` and since they aren't unique I want to get a look at how many times each String, String combination occurs so I use `countByValue` like so

```
val PairCount = Pairs.countByValue().toSeq
```

which gives me a tuple as output like this ((String,String),Long) where long is the number of times that the (String, String) tuple appeared

These Strings can be repeated in different combinations and I essentially want to run word count on this PairCount variable so I tried something like this to start:

```
PairCount.map(x => (x._1._1, x._2))
```

But the output the this spits out is String1->1, String2->1, String3->1, etc.

How do I output a key value pair from a map job in this case where the key is going to be one of the String values from the inner tuple, and the value is going to be the Long value from the outter tuple?

Update:
@vitalii gets me almost there. the answer gets me to a Seq[(String,Long)], but what I really need is to turn that into a map so that I can run reduceByKey it afterwards. when I run

```
PairCount.flatMap{case((x,y),n) => Seq[x->n]}.toMap
```

for each **unique** x I get x->1

for example the above line of code generates mom->1 dad->1 even if the tuples out of the flatMap included (mom,30) (dad,59) (mom,2) (dad,14) in which case I would expect toMap to provide mom->30, dad->59 mom->2 dad->14. However, I'm new to scala so I might be misinterpreting the functionality.

how can I get the Tuple2 sequence converted to a map so that I can reduce on the map keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the histograms for the (String,String) RDD I used this code.

```
val Hist_X  = histogram.map(x => (x._1-> 1.0)).reduceByKey(_+_).collect().toMap
val Hist_Y  = histogram.map(x => (x._2-> 1.0)).reduceByKey(_+_).collect().toMap
val Hist_XY = histogram.map(x => (x-> 1.0)).reduceByKey(_+_)
```

where histogram was the (String,String) RDD

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand question, you need flatMap:

```
val pairCountRDD = pairs.countByValue() // RDD[((String, String), Int)]
val res : RDD[(String, Int)] = pairCountRDD.flatMap { case ((s1, s2), n) =>
   Seq(s1 -> n, s2 -> n)
}
```

**Update:** I didn't quiet understand what your final goal is, but here's a few more examples that may help you, btw code above is incorrect, I have missed the fact that countByValue returns map, and not RDD:

```
val pairs = sc.parallelize(
  List(
    "mom"-> "dad", "dad" -> "granny", "foo" -> "bar", "foo" -> "baz", "foo" -> "foo"
  )
)
// don't use countByValue, if pairs is large you will run out of memmory
val pairCountRDD = pairs.map(x => (x, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _) 

val wordCount = pairs.flatMap { case (a,b) => Seq(a -> 1, b ->1)}.reduceByKey(_ + _)

wordCount.take(10)

// count in how many pairs each word occur, keys and values:
val wordPairCount = pairs.flatMap { case (a,b) => 
               if (a == b) {
                 Seq(a->1)
               } else {
                  Seq(a -> 1, b ->1)
               }
             }.reduceByKey(_ + _)
wordPairCount.take(10)
```

Comment: thanks for the input. this is a partial answer that gets me almost there. I've updated the question to detail the gaps I still have in the point A to point B connection I'm trying to make.